# Website has horrible layout issues I have no idea how to fix

Tags: html, css, layout

how the website looks for me[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utHMD.png)

Based on the monitor, my website layout and overall design is completely messed up. Alot of people have told me to put everything within a divider, but I'm still generally new, and don't know where to put it specifically. Any help at all would be extremely appreciated. I tried to make the web design liquid, but honestly I'd prefer having it be unresponsive. Any replies paired with a screenshot of how the website looks on your screen would be awesome

https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>machine girl world</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://i12.photobucket.com/albums/a213/superkate_2468/favicon-5ico.gif" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar-content-sidebar.css"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair1" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair2" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair3" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair4" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair5" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair6" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair7" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair8" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair9" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#hair11" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit1" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit2" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit3" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit4" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit5" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit6" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit7" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit8" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit9" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit10" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit11" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit12" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit13" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit14" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit15" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit16" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit17" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit18" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit19" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit19" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit20" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit21" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit22" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit23" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit24" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit25" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit26" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit27" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit28" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit29" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit30" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit31" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit32" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
     <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#outfit33" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor1" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor2" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor3" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor4" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor5" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor6" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor7" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor8" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor9" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor10" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor11" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor12" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor13" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor14" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor15" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor16" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor17" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor18" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor19" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor20" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor21" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor22" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor23" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor24" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor25" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor26" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor27" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor28" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor29" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor30" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor31" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor32" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor33" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
   <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor34" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script> <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor35" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script> 
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor36" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor37" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#decor38" ).draggable();
  } );
  </script>
<style type="text/css">* {cursor: url(https://cur.cursors-4u.net/special/spe-2/spe192.cur), auto !important;}</style><a href="https://www.cursors-4u.com/cursor/2009/02/05/i-love-my-blog.html" target="_blank" title="I Love My Blog"><img src="https://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursor.png" border="0" alt="I Love My Blog" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;" /></a>
</style>
<style>
  a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
  @font-face {
    font-family: '000webfont';
    src: url('000webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
  .mainshawty {
    left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
font-family: '000webfont';
font-size:30px;
height: 65%;
width: 37%;
overflow: scroll; 
position: absolute;
right: 400px;
top: 150px;
border: 3px outset #A1A1A1;
 padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
background-color: dimgrey;
}

  .sidebarya {
font-family: '000webfont';
font-size:20px;
overflow: hidden;
height: 72%;
width: 12%;
position: absolute;
right: 50px;
top: 120px;
border-image-slice:27 27 27 27;border-image-width:20px 20px 20px 20px;border-image-outset:0px 0px 0px 0px;border-image-repeat:stretch stretch;border-image-source:url("https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/border.png");border-style:solid;
 padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
background-color: dimgrey;
}

.body-text {
font-family: '000webfont';
margin-left: 150px;
font-size: 30px;
}
  .sidebarg {
font-family: '000webfont';
font-size:30px;
height: 72%;
width: 12%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 200;
left: 50px;
top: 120px;
overflow:hidden;
border-image-slice:27 27 27 27;border-image-width:20px 20px 20px 20px;border-image-outset:0px 0px 0px 0px;border-image-repeat:stretch stretch;border-image-source:url("https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/border.png");border-style:solid;
padding-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
background-color: dimgrey;
}

.sidebar div {
padding: 8px;
font-size: 30px;
display: block;
}

.body-text {
margin-left: 150px;
font-size: 18px;
}
.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


    
                        body {
                                background-image: url(https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/yas.gif);
                                background-position: center center;
                                background-attachment: fixed;
                                background-size: cover;
                        }
                    
  

  </style> 
  
<script language="javascript">
var titletext="i want to be real."
var repeat=true;    // SET TO true TO REPEAT, false TO "TYPE" OUT TITLE ONLY ONCE.
set=setTimeout;
var index=0;
function scrolltitle(){
if(index<=titletext.length){
document.title=titletext.substring(0,index);
index++;
set('scrolltitle()', 200);
}else{
index=0;
if(repeat)set('scrolltitle()',1000);
}}
window.onload=function(){
if(!document.layers)set('scrolltitle()',1000);
}
</script>
<body>
<div class="sidebarya">
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px;bottom:0px;"><iframe src="https://www3.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=3512307&boxtag=D3LrV1" width="200px"height="450px" allowtransparency="yes" allow="autoplay" frameborder="0"scrolling="hidden"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div class="mainshawty">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<img src="yaya.png"><br>
Doll Dressup
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href='https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/dollz1.html'>1</a>
<a href='https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/dollz2.html'>2</a>
<a href='https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/dollz3.html'>3</a>
<a href='https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/dollz4.html'>4</a>
<a href='https://xxxmachinegirlxxx.neocities.org/dollz5.html'>5</a>
<br>Heads<br>
<div id="hair1"  style="float:left;z-index:200">
 <img src="27.gif" class="drag" height="55px" width="50px"></div>
 <div id="hair2" style="float: left;z-index:200"><img src="5.gif" class="drag" height="55px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="hair3" style="float:left;z-index:200"><img src="28.gif" class="drag" height="55px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="hair4" style="float:left;z-index:200;z-index:200"><img src="44.gif" class="drag" height="50px" width="46px">
</div>
<div id="hair5" style="float:left;z-index:200"><img src="43.gif" class="drag" height="50px" width="46px">
</div>
<div id="hair6" style="float:left;z-index:200"><img src="40.gif" class="drag" height="52px" width="48px">
</div>
<div id="hair7" style="float:left;z-index:200"><img src="31.gif" class="drag" height="55px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="hair8" style="float:left;z-index:200"><img src="48.gif" class="drag" height="49px" width="44px">
</div>
<div id="hair9" style="float:left;z-index:200"><img src="49.gif" class="drag" height="57px" width="52px">
</div>
<div id="hair11" style="float:left;z-index:200"><img src="36.gif" class="drag" height="62px" width="57px">
</div>
<br><br>Outfits<br><br>
<div id="outfit1" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="1.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="outfit2" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="2.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="70px">
</div>
<div id="outfit3" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="3.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="outfit4" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="50.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="140px">
</div>
<div id="outfit5" style="float:left;z-index:199;z-index:300"><img src="22.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="outfit6" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="4.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="100px">
</div>
<div id="outfit7" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout439.gif" class="drag" height="140px" width="110px">
</div>
<div id="outfit8" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout126.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="outfit9" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout1199.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="110px">
</div>
<div id="outfit10" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout35.gif" class="drag" height="145px" width="100px">
</div>
<div id="outfit11" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout910.gif" class="drag" height="85px" width="85px">
</div>
<div id="outfit12" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout1087.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="outfit13" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout118.gif" class="drag" height="90px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="outfit14" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout795.gif" class="drag" height="160px" width="100px">
</div>
<div id="outfit15" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout354.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="outfit16" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="dress15.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="70px">
</div>
<div id="outfit17" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout959.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="110px">
</div>
<div id="outfit18" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout998.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="100px">
</div>
<div id="outfit19" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout933.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="95px">
</div>
<div id="outfit21" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout108.gif" class="drag" height="95px" width="85px">
</div>
<div id="outfit22" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="compj07.gif" class="drag" height="95px" width="95px">
</div>
<div id="outfit23" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="compj03.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="105px">
</div>
<div id="outfit24" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="comout110.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="95px">
</div>
<div id="outfit25" style="float:left;z-index:199"><img src="compj33.gif" class="drag" height="140px" width="70px">
</div>
<br><br><br>
<center>Decorations</center><br>
<div id="decor1" style="float:left"><img src="comdog45.gif" class="drag" height="45px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="decor2" style="float:left"><img src="comdog258.gif" class="drag" height="45px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="decor4" style="float:left"><img src="comdog132.gif" class="drag" height="45px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="decor3" style="float:left"><img src="6.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor5" style="float:left"><img src="12.gif" class="drag" height="60px" width="60px">
</div>
<div id="decor6" style="float:left"><img src="13.gif" class="drag" height="60px" width="60px">
</div>
<div id="decor7" style="float:left"><img src="8.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="60px">
</div>
<div id="decor8" style="float:left"><img src="9.gif" class="drag" height="60px" width="60px">
</div>
<div id="decor9" style="float:left"><img src="comxmasan22.gif" class="drag" height="60px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor10" style="float:left"><img src="comcat10.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor11" style="float:left"><img src="comcat01.gif" class="drag" height="35px" width="35px">
</div>
<div id="decor12" style="float:left"><img src="comdog12 (1).gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor13" style="float:left"><img src="comtoy47.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor14" style="float:left"><img src="comlove04.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor15" style="float:left"><img src="comlove06.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor16" style="float:left"><img src="comlove02.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor17" style="float:left"><img src="25.gif" class="drag" height="60px" width="60px">
</div>
<div id="decor18" style="float:left"><img src="18.gif" class="drag" height="60px" width="60px">
</div>
<div id="decor19" style="float:left"><img src="comele03.gif" class="drag" height="40px" width="40px">
</div>
<div id="decor20" style="float:left"><img src="comlamp12.gif" class="drag" height="50px" width="20px">
</div>
<div id="decor21" style="float:left"><img src="comcompw32.gif" class="drag" height="70px" width="45px">
</div>
Furniture
<br><br>
<div id="decor22" style="float:left;z-index:1"><img src="comcomp05.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="145px">
</div>
<div id="decor23" style="float:left;z-index:1"><img src="comcomp13.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="145px">
</div>
<div id="decor24" style="float:left;z-index:1"><img src="comcomp03.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="145px">
</div>
<div id="decor25" style="float:left;z-index:1"><img src="comcomp35.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="145px">
</div>
<div id="decor26" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comseat128.gif" class="drag" height="110px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="decor38" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comseat128a.gif" class="drag" height="110px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="decor34" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comseat140.gif" class="drag" height="110px" width="90px">
</div>
<div id="decor27" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="combed22.gif" class="drag" height="150px" width="220px">
</div>
<div id="decor28" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="combed02.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="240">
</div>
<div id="decor29" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="combed04.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="230">
</div>
<div id="decor30" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comseat44.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="230">
</div>
<div id="decor31" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comfur06.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="80px">
</div>
<div id="decor32" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comfur33.gif" class="drag" height="50px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="decor33" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comframe14.gif" class="drag" height="50px" width="50px">
</div>
<div id="decor35" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="aqu75a.gif" class="drag" height="140px" width="100px">
</div>
<div id="decor36" style="float:left;z-index:2"><img src="comdog142.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="100px">
</div>
<div id="decor37" style="float:left;z-index:0"><img src="comrug62.gif" class="drag" height="100px" width="160px">
</div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sidebarg">
<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a><br><a href="favorites.html">Favorites</a><br><a href="whathappened.html">Home</a><br><a href="adviceforum.html">Advice</a><br><a href="luna.html">Luna</a><br><a href="diary.html">Diary</a><br><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a><br><a href="goodies.html">Goodies</a><br><a href="dollz.html">Dolls</a><br>mood<a href="https://www.imood.com/users/jazzdog12"><img src="https://moods.imood.com/display/uname-jazzdog12/fg-000000/trans-1/imood.gif" alt="The current mood of jazzdog12 at www.imood.com" width="100" height="15"></a><br><script language="JavaScript">var fhs = document.createElement('script');var fhs_id = "5670617";
var ref = (''+document.referrer+'');var pn =  window.location;var w_h = window.screen.width + " x " + window.screen.height;
fhs.src = "//freehostedscripts.net/ocounter.php?site="+fhs_id+"&e1=Online &e2=Online &r="+ref+"&wh="+w_h+"&a=1&pn="+pn+"";
document.head.appendChild(fhs);document.write("<span id='o_"+fhs_id+"'></span>");
</script>
<img src="insanedoll.gif"></div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 0%; top:3%;z-index:1000;translate(4%, -7%);display: flex;
  justify-content: center;">
<img src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/88a30b3a680ea1b596124eb40d05f522/ad1af1aa6edf17ff-44/s250x400/2b5679baba0f0ba3c1404743d8b07037a5670ac4.gifv"width="250" height="100">
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 21%; top:5%; z-index:1000;transform: translate(2%, -45%);">
<img src="me.png"width="250">
</div>
<div style=" position: relative; left: 62%; bottom:0%;z-index:1000;transform: translate(-3%, -145%);">
<img src="image.png"width="250">
</div>
<iframe width="0" height="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QGWQ3mSAXl8?autoplay=1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 'completely messed up' doesn't really tell us what the site should look like as opposed to what it looks like now. Could you describe more what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**I.** You've imported two jQuer"ies" (3.2.1 and 3.6.0) on the same site, delete one.

**II.** This way to make drag-able items isn't smart. try using a `draggable` class. An example below.

HTML:

```html
<div id="hair1" class="draggable">
    <img src="example.gif" type="image/gif"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```

**III.** The inline CSS should appears in a `.css` file for a better maintainability.

**IV.** Format your code(s), also, for a better maintainability.

These are some suggestions for you. Hope them helps.